# React Native Geolocation: Why is this async function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, geolocation, asynchronous-javascript

I have the following function:

```
func = async () => {
    let location = await getLocation();
    console.log(location)
}
```

it calls this function

```
getLocation = async () => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            return 1
        }
    );
};
```

When I debug, I find that the code does indeed reach the `return 1` line, but in `func` it always sets `location` to `undefined`. Am I doing something wrong with the asynchronous call here?

Comment: you have no return statements from `getLocation`  - therefore undefined is returned - and since `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't return a promise, there's no point in making `getLocation` an `async` function - note: `async/await` is syntax sugar for Promises - and your core function (`Geolocation.getCurrentPosition`) doesn't use Promises

Comment: simply change to `const getLocation = () => new Promise(resolve => Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve))` ... note, `getLocation` is NOT, and does not need to be `async`

Comment: @JaromandaX This is the solution, thank you. If you want to put this as an answer, including that in `func()` you have to add `then()` to `getLocation()` I can accept it.